# Discord.py Storing and Outputting Records/Warnings

Tags: python, discord.py

So currently I am trying to create a blacklist (basically a warn command) command where server owners can use the command to publish bans they dealt with. I tried to rewrite my original warn command but the problem with that is the output isn't how I wanted it to be and if I did want to fix it, I had to rewrite a majority of the code which is why I wanted to make a new fresh command for it.

So the problem I am facing with making the command is taking in multiple arguments.

Eg: (Process of blacklisting)

```
User: >blacklist (user/id)

BOT: Gamertag?

User: *Sends an Xbox username*

BOT: Banned from?

User: *Sends server name*

BOT: Reason for the ban?

User: *Sends ban reason*
```

This is an example of the conversation the bot and user would be going through. The main thing is being able to save the user's responses and send everything as an embed.
I currently have this:

```py
@commands.command()
async def blacklist(self, ctx):
 embed = discord.Embed(title = "Blacklist Report")
 #Then something here to collect responses
```

Note: I can create the embed just fine but just need help collecting responses from the user. Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to send you 2 functions I always use to help you out

```py
def check_message(author: discord.User, channel: discord.TextChannel, forbid: bool = False):
    def check(message: discord.Message):
        if forbid and message.channel.id == channel.id and message.author.id != author.id and message.author.id != bot.user.id:
            embed = discord.Embed(title='**ERROR**', description=f'Only {author.mention} can send message here', colour=discord.Colour.red())
            asyncio.ensure_future(message.delete())
            asyncio.ensure_future(channel.send(embed=embed, delete_after=20))

        return message.author.id == author.id and channel.id == message.channel.id

    return check

async def get_answer(ctx: discord.TextChannel, user: discord.User, embed: discord.Embed, timeout: Optional[int] = None, delete_after: bool = False) -> Optional[str]:
    message: discord.Message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    try:
        respond: discord.Message = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check_message(user, ctx), timeout=timeout)

        if delete_after:
            await try_delete(message)
            await try_delete(respond)

        return respond.content
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        if delete_after:
            await try_delete(message)

        return None
```

You don't need to even call `check_message`, You just need to await the `get_answer` and get what you want as a string

Here is an example:

```py
@commands.command('example')
async def example(self, ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title='What is your name?')
    response = await get_answer(ctx.channel, ctx.author, embed)
    print(f'His name was {response}') # or any other thing you want to use it for
```

The `timeout` allows you to close the process after some seconds without response and continue the code, In that case you will get `None` as the output of this function.

The `delete_after` allows you to remove both the question message and the response one after timeout or reciving a response to keep chat clear.

Comment: Wouldn't this send an embed for each question/response? Is there a way to group all of the responses into one embed instead of sending multiple messages.

Comment: @SpaceTurtle0 You have asked for sth that first get a command and then start asking for other things after that
If you are looking for getting all data in one command use arguments in your command then